# How do you find the minimum value in a 2-D array excluding 0s?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`list = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0], [0, 4, 5, 6, 0], [0, 8, 9, 10, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

I want to find the minimum value of this using only loops and min/max methods and make them exclude 0s. Is there a way to do this? **I do not want to import any libraries.**

I've tried the following code but it returns 0.

`minimum = min([min(r) for r in temp_list if r != 0])`

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: Is your expected output is minimum list or integer?

Comment: minimum = min([min(r) for r in list if r != 0]) is what I've tried but it just returns 0. I need an integer @shaikmoeed

Comment: Please move your code to your question, don't post it in comments

Comment: Can there be negative values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use **built-in functions as variables**

You need to iterate over the inner-list as well to eliminate `0's`.

Try this,

```
>>> l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0], [0, 4, 5, 6, 0], [0, 8, 9, 10, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> min([i for r in l for i in r if i != 0])
1
```

**Explanation:**

- Created a `1-D list` without `0's`
- Taking `min` value of that list

Comment: That seems to work. Could you put that code in words, please? Just trying to understand it

Comment: Also, I'm trying to find the lowest value of all adjacent cells, similar to this screenshot. https://gyazo.com/c81237d703963d1905dce786ed0e8f0e
Can a similar method be applied for this?

Comment: @adil.a *lowest value of all adjacent cells*, If your finding the lowest value from a 2-D array, a similar method is applicable.

Comment: @adil.a Don't forget to accept the answer, if it clears your issue.